# Mysql insert query error count column doesn't match

Tags: c#, mysql, database

Ugh manual version of the query functions idk why it doesn't want to work the variable types are correct can someone help me

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Code:

```
myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO kooien( kooidlistppg, quarantaine, vasteoflossekooie, bezetofniet, NummerExtern) VALUES (' ?kooidlisttoppg, ?quarantaine, ?vasteoflossekooie, ?bezetofniet, ?NummerExtern')";

myCommand.Parameters.Add("?kooidlistppg", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = kooidlistpphg;
myCommand.Parameters.Add("?quarantaine", MySqlDbType.Byte).Value = qarant;
myCommand.Parameters.Add("?vasteoflossekooie", MySqlDbType.Byte).Value = morv;
myCommand.Parameters.Add("?bezetofniet", MySqlDbType.Byte).Value = bezofnie;
myCommand.Parameters.Add("?NummerExtern", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = kooi.Kooinr;

myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove ' from insert query

```
myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO kooien( kooidlistppg, quarantaine, vasteoflossekooie, bezetofniet, NummerExtern) VALUES ( ?kooidlisttoppg, ?quarantaine, ?vasteoflossekooie, ?bezetofniet, ?NummerExtern)";
```